# If X involves Y, does it imply that X always has Y?

Tags: logic

If X(process) involves Y(action)

Does it imply that

Y(action) is ALWAYS part of X(process)?

I think this question revolves around the definition of 'involves'

Comment: Is this homework? Basic answer: it depends on how "involve" and "has" are defined.

Comment: No, this is not homework...just thinking of a question I recently was given

Comment: Fair enough. It is an interesting issue. (And I appreciate that it's simpler than many of the questions we get here).

Comment: This looks like it fits the "definitions of words" close reason.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly; if by "X involves Y" we mean "Y is required by X" we can try with the following counter-example :

> "To drive a car *involves* to own a driving license";
>
> > therefore "A driving license is always owned by someone driving a car".

If instead we mean : "Y is *entailed* by X", then things are different.

Answer (score 1):

The question is indeed a little vague. My journey to work involves me getting in my car and driving. Does this imply that I always drive my car to work? In fact, I always have driven to work, but it seems reasonable to say that I needn't: I could walk or take a bus.

If one is talking about processes and actions in the real world, there are always going to be such possibilities, i.e. exceptions or defeating conditions that mean we can't say for certain that something is always so.

One might wish to embrace some kind of essentialism, i.e. to say that Y is essential to X and therefore must always be present. Plato and Aristotle taught this, though their versions of essentialism have few adherents these days. More recently Kripke and Putnam have adopted a kind of essentialism in respect of the origins of things.

Incidentally, if you wish to read more about this, the Wikipedia articles on these subjects are pretty weak. You would do better to read the Stanford Encyclopedia entry on Natural Kinds, and if you are very brave, follow it up with the entry on two-dimensional semantics.